# How To Highlight Roads?

Tags: google-maps, layers

I wish to change the colors of various roads on a map and save the changes to either a "personal map" or a "map layer."

The personal map could look something like [this](https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msid=213561568035843414319.0004ddce5d7abe1d2241b&msa=0), except it would need to have the "snap to roads" feature, which is currently bugged on google mymaps.

The map layer option seems a lot more complicated, but would be ideal if combined with a wiki function as the entire point of this exercise is to color roads according to a cyclist's perspective: according to speed and volume of traffic.

It would be ideal if the road itself could be selected and highlighted so that any changes to the road would automatically be incorporated into the color scheme--instead of having colors going where the road no longer goes.

I am not necessarily asking for a detailed step-by-step walkthrough of a specific possibility (though that would be nice), but rather a general overview of what my options are and hopefully some idea as to which options are most promising. I have been researching [various mapping systems](http://www.netmagazine.com/features/top-seven-alternatives-google-maps-api) for several hours and feel as if I'm re-inventing the wheel. Please suggest a method for highlighting roads.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer of this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513360/polyline-snap-to-road-using-google-maps-api-v3

can move your further on the road.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenBikeMap.com](http://www.opencyclemap.org/) Intends to do essentially what I desired. Each road is a set of GPS points collectively refereed to as a "way." Thus each road may be selected and classified as: motorway, trunk road, primary road, secondary road, tertiary road, residential road, unclassified road. Thus each road is classified already and highlighting is unnecessary.

Comment: Are you saying that this answers your question?  If so, or if not, can you expand upon your answer by editing it to make that clearer, please?